WinForms application UI thread is help up by fast updating TreeListView
I currently have a WinForms application where I display data in a TreeListView. The data is CAN messages, and it is currently setup to update the treelistview as soon as a new CAN message is detected. The main navigation is a tab control that switches between different functionalities and processing of the incoming CAN messages.
The problem comes when switching from any tab, to the tab where my treelistview is. Whenever the CAN messages starting coming in at an interval of 10ms or so, the problem arises. The treelistview gets painted and updated as I want, but all the other controls do not even paint at all, nevermind being interactive. The previous page I was on with the tabcontrol, also is still displayed, so the treelistview gets drawn over the old tabpage, without any other controls being drawn and the old tabpage still displaying, although non-interactive.
I tried to make so that whenever you switch to the tabpage with the CAN messages, it stops processing the CAN messages for a short while so the UI thread can at least paint the the other controls, and it did work. The other controls did paint, but were still not interactive. I could not click on any buttons or select anything on my other controls.
Currently its setup that another background thread is used to check for new messages, and trigger an event when a message is detected to process that message. The data processing is then done on another thread, and finally it pushes the data to the UI thread to update the UI.
A few weeks ago, I was using a normal ListView, and then none of these faults happened, only now when I switched to a treelistview did this start happening.
Here is some code in the processing of the message:
`    string sFullPGN = data.completePGN;
if (sTxtBoxPGNDisplay == sFullPGN)
    txtBoxTxInfo.Text = getRxTooltip(ref data);

if (CAN_PGNS.Contains(sFullPGN))
{
    int index = GetAdapterIndex(sFullPGN);
    if (index != -1)
    {

        Adapters[index].UpdateAdapterData(data);

        if (Adapters[index].Children != null) // Does the PGN contain any signals?
        foreach(CANAdapter signal in Adapters[index].Children)
        {
            signal.UpdateChild(data);
        }
        // RefreshObject gives an error if a filter is applied, complains about index error since ObjectListView uses it own internal display list 
        // which is changed when a filter is applied. The All objects list's index is then taken directly instead of being adapted to the 
        // display list's matching showing index. This is all internal code of the ObjectListView and cannot be changed by us.
        // See line btnCHfilter_click below.

        //tlvCANIn.RefreshObject(Adapters[index]);
        try { tlvCANIn.RefreshObject(Adapters[index]); } catch {}   
    }
}
else
{
    CANAdapter newAdapter = new CANAdapter(sFullPGN);
    CanMessageInfo newMessage = new CanMessageInfo();
   
    newMessage = CANMessagesInfo.GetMessage(data.PGN_RBDP);
    newAdapter.UpdateAdapterData(data);
    if (newMessage != null)
    {
        newAdapter.comment = newMessage.name + " " + newMessage.comment;
        if (newMessage.signals.Count > 0)
        {
            newAdapter.HasSPNs = true;
            newAdapter.InitialiseChildren(newMessage.signals);
        }
        else
        {
            newAdapter.HasSPNs = false;
        }
    }
    Adapters.Add(newAdapter);
    CAN_PGNS.Add(sFullPGN);
}

}`

This is what happens when you update the UI at a rate higher than it can paint itself.  It can never keep up.  Not the only victim, your user's eyes can't keep up either.  Rethink your UI design first.  A Q&D fix might be to update the TLV not for every message but, say, 20 at a time.

This program is almost as old as winforms itself, so I have considered starting completely over in something like WPF, not entirely sure if WPF performance is bette? As far as I understand I have more control over UI rendering so maybe I can wrangle something with that.

The best solution I found was to limit the UI update rate but still process the CAN messages as they come in with a timer update. I add all the objects that needs to be updated into a list and update that list with tlvMyTreeListView.RefreshObject(objectToRefresh) in the timer callback
